# MVC dropdownlistfor add null value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html.dropdownlistfor

I am working in MVC 
I added a "select all" option to a DropDownListFor as such

```
<tr><td valign="top">@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.fk_Type, Model.ListType, "- Select All -", new { style = "width:210px" })</td></tr>
```

In my Controller code the select all option is giving a value of "". Which i assume is an empty string.
Is there a way in the html above to set the value of 'select all' to null.
That would make the called stor proc in the model, handle it perfectly..
many thanks

Answer (score 0):

No.  "null" has special meaning to a drop down list, and that meaning is "unselected".  In your case, there is a value selected, but it's a default value, so it can't be null.